# Using {category_name} as an CSS class

Tags: templates, categories, parameters

I am trying to use the parameter {category_name} a css class on my site [click here](http://bodyworksforme.com/?/blog)

on the slide show, you'll notice a green tag which says, "sport" underneath that tag is another tag labelled "energy" I am using the category name's to call out this css properties. I have noticed in inspector all the category names are appearing in the script however i only want one category name to appear.

I have applied the following code:
              `

```
            {exp:channel:categories channel="blog" style="linear" show_empty="no" }
    <div class="cat-box-tab {category_name}"></div>
    {/exp:channel:categories}`
```

what other parameters do i need to apply to only display one category name per post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the category a post is in, then you'll want to use the {categories} ([doc link](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories)) tag instead.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}

<div class="cat-box-tab {categories}{category_name}{/categories}"></div>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Mel you're a legend!!!

Comment: You might want to consider using {category_url_title} instead of {category_name} to avoid issues with spaces in category names.

Comment: And add a space after that for when you have multiple categories assigned to an entry. (if you are very precise you could use the backspace parameter too)(e.g. `{categories backspace="1"}{category_url_title} {/categories}`

Answer (score 2):

Specifically add limit=1 if you only want 1 category.
`{categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/categories}`